# dynamodb -inMemory mode not working as expected in Docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, amazon-dynamodb

I'm experiencing an issue with DynamoDB and Docker that I am having difficulty troubleshooting. The gist of it is that we are running DynamoDB in memory (--inMemory) and have some provisioning code that creates and populates some tables. Previously, this provisioning code was running locally (on the host OS) in a shell script.

I've moved this code into a Docker container. We're using Docker Compose to build and run the containers:

```
dynamodb:
  container_name: "dynamodb"
  image: amazon/dynamodb-local
  ports:
    - "18000:18000"
  command: -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -inMemory -port 18000

load-dynamodb:
  container_name: "load-dynamodb"
  image: myaccountid.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/path/aws-cli
  volumes:
    - ./_scripts/provision-dynamo-db.sh:/usr/local/bin/provision-dynamo-db.sh
    - ./_scripts/dynamodb.sh:/usr/local/bin/dynamodb.sh
    - ./_scripts/logging.sh:/usr/local/bin/logging.sh
    - ./configuration/dynamo_auth_config_ida_sp.json:/etc/conf/dynamo_auth_config_ida_sp.json
    - ./configuration/dynamo_auth_config_mock.json:/etc/conf/dynamo_auth_config_mock.json
    - ./configuration/dynamo_org_data.json:/etc/conf/dynamo_org_data.json
  command: "/usr/local/bin/provision-dynamo-db.sh"
  depends_on:
    - dynamodb
  environment:
    - AWS_REGION=${AWS_REGION}
    - AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}
    - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}
    - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
```

It appears to run fine:

```
dynamodb                 | Initializing DynamoDB Local with the following configuration:
dynamodb                 | Port:    18000
dynamodb                 | InMemory:    true
dynamodb                 | DbPath:  null
dynamodb                 | SharedDb:    false
dynamodb                 | shouldDelayTransientStatuses:    false
dynamodb                 | CorsParams:  *
dynamodb                 |
```

I see the tables being created and populated in the logs:

```
Attaching to load-dynamodb
load-dynamodb            | 2019-10-21 16:33:59  Loading dev environment auth configuration
load-dynamodb            | Connecting to http://dynamodb:18000...
load-dynamodb            | {
load-dynamodb            |     "TableDescription": {
load-dynamodb            |         "TableArn": "arn:aws:dynamodb:ddblocal:000000000000:table/auth-config", 
load-dynamodb            |         "AttributeDefinitions": [
load-dynamodb            |             {
load-dynamodb            |                 "AttributeName": "customer_id", 
load-dynamodb            |                 "AttributeType": "S"
load-dynamodb            |             }, 
load-dynamodb            |             {
load-dynamodb            |                 "AttributeName": "name", 
load-dynamodb            |                 "AttributeType": "S"
load-dynamodb            |             }
load-dynamodb            |         ], 
load-dynamodb            |         "ProvisionedThroughput": {
load-dynamodb            |             "NumberOfDecreasesToday": 0, 
load-dynamodb            |             "WriteCapacityUnits": 10, 
load-dynamodb            |             "LastIncreaseDateTime": 0.0, 
load-dynamodb            |             "ReadCapacityUnits": 10, 
load-dynamodb            |             "LastDecreaseDateTime": 0.0
load-dynamodb            |         }, 
load-dynamodb            |         "TableSizeBytes": 0, 
load-dynamodb            |         "TableName": "auth-config", 
load-dynamodb            |         "TableStatus": "ACTIVE", 
load-dynamodb            |         "StreamSpecification": { 
load-dynamodb            |             "StreamViewType": "NEW_IMAGE", 
load-dynamodb            |             "StreamEnabled": true
load-dynamodb            |         }, 
load-dynamodb            |         "LatestStreamLabel": "2019-10-21T16:34:02.184", 
load-dynamodb            |         "KeySchema": [
load-dynamodb            |             {
load-dynamodb            |                 "KeyType": "HASH", 
load-dynamodb            |                 "AttributeName": "customer_id"
load-dynamodb            |             }, 
load-dynamodb            |             {
load-dynamodb            |                 "KeyType": "RANGE", 
load-dynamodb            |                 "AttributeName": "name"
load-dynamodb            |             }
load-dynamodb            |         ], 
load-dynamodb            |         "ItemCount": 0, 
load-dynamodb            |         "CreationDateTime": 1571675642.184, 
load-dynamodb            |         "LatestStreamArn": "arn:aws:dynamodb:ddblocal:000000000000:table/auth-config/stream/2019-10-21T16:34:02.184"
load-dynamodb            |     }
load-dynamodb            | }
load-dynamodb            | Verifying auth-config...
load-dynamodb            | {
load-dynamodb            |     "Count": 2, 
load-dynamodb            |     "ScannedCount": 2, 
load-dynamodb            |     "ConsumedCapacity": null
load-dynamodb            | }
```

When a different container tries to retrieve the data, the data is missing. DescribeTable says it is a "non-existent" table and it gets created again (without the data that is needed):

```
auth_service             | An error occurred (ResourceNotFoundException) when calling the DescribeTable operation: Cannot do operations on a non-existent table
auth_service             | Creating table auth-config
auth_service             | {
auth_service             |     "TableDescription": {
auth_service             |         "TableArn": "arn:aws:dynamodb:ddblocal:000000000000:table/auth-config",
```

One theory I had was that we were connecting as a different user, and thus, a different namespace. However, according to the DynamoDB docs, that is not the case:

> The AWS SDKs for DynamoDB require that your application configuration
>   specify an access key value and an AWS Region value. Unless you're
>   using the -sharedDb or the -inMemory option, DynamoDB uses these
>   values to name the local database file. These values don't have to be
>   valid AWS values to run locally. However, you might find it convenient
>   to use valid values so that you can run your code in the cloud later
>   simply by changing the endpoint you're using.

Also, I ruled out that it is connecting to the wrong instance, by bringing up a shell in a new Docker container, connecting to the database at the endpoint (http://dynamodb:18000), listing the empty set of tables, bringing down the DynamoDb container and then attempting to connect. As expected, after bringing down DynamoDB, the aws client fails to connect.

So, having ruled out that we are connecting to the wrong instance, is it possible that there is something in the environment that causes the aws dynamodb client to connect to a different database? My understanding is that AWS credentials and region are ignored due to the fact it's running with -inMemory. What about the network itself? The provisioning code is now running on the Docker network instead of the host network.

I'm at a loss, any suggestions would be appreciated.

---

UPDATE:

- Seems that the AWS_DEFAULT_REGION affects the query results even when endpoint-url is specified.

I shelled into the load-dynamodb container and queried for the table. I see the expected results (auth-config contains 2 entries).

AWS_DEFAULT_REGION is not set. I set it:

```
$ export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
```

Now the query shows zero entries:

```
bash-4.4# aws dynamodb --endpoint-url http://dynamodb:18000 describe-table --table-name auth-config
..."ItemCount": 0...
```

I'm not sure why it would matter since we're overriding the endpoint-url, but since it appears to be significant, my guess is the dependent container must be specifying a different set of environment variables or forming the dynamodb query differently.

Am I missing something in the docs that would explain this behavior in the awscli client?

Comment: I'm curious, what happens if you start DynamoDB local with both the sharedDb and inMemory options (you can specify both although the docs may imply otherwise), does the behavior change?

Comment: Any progress on this, I'm now curious to know what was the root cause?

Comment: I tried these options together and didn't notice anything. It appears that AWS_DEFAULT_REGION was set in one client, while not in the other. If I set it to the same value, then the connection shows the data I was expecting. This is not expected behavior since ENDPOINT_URL is specified. The other strange thing is the table ARN shows "ddblocal" as the region, so it doesn't appear this variable is even used.

Comment: It seems this has nothing to do with Docker either. It is a side effect of moving the code into a Docker container and not setting the environment variables consistently across containers.

Comment: Good to know, thanks.  Please consider creating an answer from your findings as I'm sure this will help others in the future.

Comment: I agree, please create an answer for this to capture what you did and the resolution.